# Unable to Load Windows 8.1 After Dualbooting with Linux

Tags: 14.04, dual-boot, windows-8

I am very new to Linux and have come across this error when trying to fix the boot issues. If anyone has any advice or even the answer to my problem, please let me know so I can successfully reboot my Windows 8 alongside my Ubuntu!
Here is the link to my error report:
http://paste.ubuntu.com/10365235/

Comment: It looks like you left it hibernated. That caused all sorts of issues. Best not to have "Fast Boot" or always on hibernation on. Grub entries for Windows will not work. Have you tried directly booting from UEFI menu the Windows entry? The efibootmgr -v entry did not even show the Windows entry?

Comment: How do I boot from the UEFI menu? I'm sorry I'm very new to this. I had done this with the help of a friend around midnight so we may have made mistakes due to tiredness. But once again sorry for all of the trouble. Thanks!

Comment: The blue screen example shows a typical UEFI boot menu. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI But you have to check manual for your system to know how to get into UEFI. Some have a fast boot in UEFI, separate from fast boot in BIOS and you may have to cold boot, or turn off power, remove battery if laptop and hold power switch for 10 sec to drain all power. Then press correct key immediately on booting. Manual should say if del, f1 or f2 or other combinations of keys are required.

Comment: I got to the system settings menu and looked through it. It seemed to be stuck in a UEFI boot mode (the setting was colored gray and upon trying to scroll down to it, it completely skipped the option) I also do not believe I have my Toshiba Satellite C-55A's Manual anymore :/ I removed my battery to try and "cold boot" but I hadn't seen what it may have done...(once again I apologize for my lack of cpu knowledge) I tried running an fdsk on /dev/sda and apparently my files may be corrupt on  that drive...I don't know if this could be a major part of the problem or not.

Comment: fdisk does not work on gpt drives. Only if you have abnormal shutdown might you need fsck. Usually removing battery resets all settings back to defaults. So you have to go back into UEFI and turn off secure boot, but leave UEFI on. Turn off UEFI fast boot and maybe other settings. You should be able to find a manual on-line. See also this thread: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2247186 or this which are not your exact model and older version of Ubuntu but otherwise  similar: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2216279

Answer (score 0):

After seeing your error report I was wondering, since I had Ubuntu 14.04 alongside with Windows 8.1. But for dual booting I made legacy mode enabled so after 2/3 months my pc started facing problems. As this legacy setting should be disabled for Windows 8/8.1. So am using it in VM ware now. So I think if you are using licensed copy of windows then don't use dual booting because it may cause problems while booting of windows, prefer using Virtual machine and if you are having pirated version of windows see once boot-up settings. From your error report I came to know one thing that may be you haven't done the disk partition well enough. But still if you want to use ubuntu 14.04 alongside windows 8, then change the boot-up settings not Grub settings.

Comment: I'm sorry but I'm very new to this. How do I change the boot settings instead of the grub settings? Sorry for all of the trouble. Thanks!